# What is the style of illustration on this sculpture called?

Tags: style-identification, art

What is this style of illustration called? I'd also be interested in the artists name. A friend from Chicago sent this to me. It reminded me of posters from New Orleans that I'd seen for Mardi Gras, but googling that didn't really help illuminate anything. I believe in the picture it looks as if it's moulded plastic, I'm pretty sure it's not folded cloth.

[image: Looking for this style]
[[image: Example of Mardi Gras posters][2](https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/6187763/il_fullxfull.282742469.jpg)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not meet our [style-identification guidelines](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2929/23061)

Comment: I can conform to the guidelines, I wasn't aware there were any. Thanks for sharing them!

Comment: Your question is actually older than our guidelines, haha :) But it still needs to fit them. Would you mind also changing the title to something more descriptive? Another image of the style would also be useful

Answer (score 1):

That's probably "art deco". Google it, there are tons of almost same illustrations floating on web

Comment: Art Deco predates braided headbands by several decades.

Comment: You seem to be right sphere42:  http://www.citrinitas.com/history_of_viscom/modernists.html and https://www.google.com/search?q=art+deco+design&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMI1fWa3JzSxwIVwTY-Ch1ACwV-&biw=1178&bih=865#tbm=isch&q=art+deco+graphic+design

Comment: @DA01 This actually reminds me a bit of Patrick Nagel, who was definitely influenced by art deco (and some even classify his art style as such).

Comment: @vickiebberts yea, I agree.